# How to integrate reCaptcha on an SSL site with Java library?

Tags: java, ssl, https, recaptcha

So there is a well documented issue with people who have stale URL's pointing to:

```
https://api-secure.recaptcha.net/challenge<etc,etc>
```

The new URL is supposed to be:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/XXX
```

That's all well and good, but I'm using Google's reCaptcha library as described here:

```
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/java
```

You'll notice the only version is 0.07 and uploaded in 2007, 4 years before the 2011 announcement of the URL change.  There is no newer version of the library offered post 2011's URL shift from what I can tell.  Does anyone know of such a library for we lowly Java devs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to do this:

```
((ReCaptchaImpl) captcha).setRecaptchaServer("google.com/recaptcha/api";);
```

Hope that helps someone who stumbles into this problem